# Shallow HOC with Enzyme and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I have a HOC to test, during shallow mount I should to call some class methods:

```
it('Should not call dispatch', () => {
        const dispatch = jest.fn()
        const WrappedComponent = someHoc(DummyComponent)
        const instance = shallow(
          <WrappedComponent
            dispatch={dispatch}
          />,
        ).instance() as WrappedComponent
        instance.someMethod()
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
})
```

test works fine but TS compiler throws an error

```
 Cannot find name 'WrappedComponent'.
```

And it is right because WrappedComponent is not a type or class,
but if I remove the

```
 as WrappedComponent
```

line, TS throws an error

```
Property 'someMethod' does not exist on type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.
```

Also, it does not compile if I change that line as

```
as typeof WrappedComponent
```

someHoc description:

```
import ...

interface State {
  /*state*/
}

interface Props {
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>
  /*props*/
}

export someHoc = <T extends {}>(
  ChildComponent: React.ComponentClass<T>,
) => {
  class Wrapper extends React.PureComponent<T & Props, State> {

    someMethod = () => {
       /*do smth*/
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ChildComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return Wrapper
}
```

How can I type the HOC instance? Thanks.

Comment: What's `someHoc`? How is it typed? *Also, it does not compile if I change that line as* - what is the error?

Comment: @estus just added some description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is expected that functions that have variable return value types that can be parametrized are generics. [`shallow` is a generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5a86a73eec28891f05b070034d068fa616fc5c51/types/enzyme/index.d.ts#L599-L601):

```
export function shallow<C extends Component, P = C['props'], S = C['state']>(node: ReactElement<P>, options?: ShallowRendererProps): ShallowWrapper<P, S, C>;
export function shallow<P>(node: ReactElement<P>, options?: ShallowRendererProps): ShallowWrapper<P, any>;
export function shallow<P, S>(node: ReactElement<P>, options?: ShallowRendererProps): ShallowWrapper<P, S>;
```

It likely should be used as:

```
const instance = shallow<typeof WrappedComponent>(
  <WrappedComponent
    dispatch={dispatch}
  />,
).instance();
```

There currently seem to be problems in Enzyme typings with using generic parameters to infer component type in `ShallowWrapper`.

A workaround that secures type safety down the test is to assert the type:

```
const instance = shallow(
  <WrappedComponent
    dispatch={dispatch}
  />,
)
.instance() as any as InstanceType<typeof WrappedComponent>;
```

Comment: the same error ` Cannot find name 'WrappedComponent'.` And `Property 'someMethod' does not exist on type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.` if I use `typeof WrappedComponent`

Comment: Works if do `shallow<typeof WrappedComponent>` and `.instance() as any`, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, it's `typeof`. On second thought, this looks like a bug in Enzyme typings. I was just about to suggest to type it as `.instance() as any as typeof WrappedComponent` and move along.

Comment: `.instance() as any as typeof WrappedComponent` is not working, so yes, looks like as some kind of bug.

Comment: Sorry, sure, it's `InstanceType<typeof WrappedComponent>`, since `typeof WrappedComponent` is the constructor itself. Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about `HOC`, but in case anyone finds this after Googling for hours, try updating `@types/react` to the latest version (I went from `18.0.14` to `18.2.38`).

Which allowed me to use (unmodified)

```
const about = shallow(<About />);
```

given

```
export default function About() {
  const foo = true;
  return (
    <div>Blabla</div>
  )
}
```

with no problems.